# Testing a FieldSetMapper which reads by column names throws exception

Tags: spring-batch

The line mapping logic in the job config xml is as follows:

```
<property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="names" value="ID,NAME"/>
        <property name="strict" value="false"/>
    </bean>
</property>
<property name="fieldSetMapper">
    <bean class="com.company.batch.mappers.EmpFieldSetMapper"/>
</property>
```

The field set mapper read logic is as follows:

```
fieldSet.readString("ID");
```

But while writing UT for `EmpFieldSetMapper`, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot access columns by name without meta data

    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.indexOf(DefaultFieldSet.java:675)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.readString(DefaultFieldSet.java:169)
```

The UT is as follows:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mapper = new EmpFieldSetMapper();
    DefaultFieldSetFactory fieldSetFactory = new DefaultFieldSetFactory();

    String[] inputValues = { "123", "RAJ" };
    fieldSet = fieldSetFactory.create(inputValues);
}

@Test
public void testMapFieldSet() {
    try {
        Model model = mapper.mapFieldSet(fieldSet);
        assertEquals("ID field mapping is wrong", "123", model.getId());
        assertEquals("NAME field mapping is wrong", "RAJ", model.getName());
    } catch (BindException e) {
        fail("Exception during field set mapping");
    }
}
```

I think I need to change the `DefaultFieldSetMapper` to something else but unsure about it. This issue can be resolved by replacing the column names with index but I want to retain the column names in `EmpFieldSetMapper`. So need suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Need to pass in column names as well.

```
String[] inputValues = { "123", "RAJ" };
String[] inputColumns = { "ID", "NAME" };
fieldSet = fieldSetFactory.create(inputValues, inputColumns);
```